# Diferença entre Datas JS - Erro momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Necessito calcular a diferença entre duas datas informadas.
Preciso saber o resultado em anos meses e dias.
Usei a biblioteca momentjs em conjunto com o angularjs.

Ao colocar a dataInicial como 06/07/2015 e a data de nascimento como 06/07/1957, **o resultado esperado seria 58 anos 0 meses e 0 dias.**
Mas o resultado obtido foi **58 anos 0 meses e 6 dias**

A função em JS que faz essa conversão é a seguinte:

```
function converterData(){

    var hoje = moment($scope.final, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var dia  = moment($scope.nascimento, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var duracao = moment.duration(hoje.valueOf()- dia.valueOf(), 'milliseconds');
                    $scope.idadeAnos =  duracao.years();
                    $scope.idadeMeses =  duracao.months();
                    $scope.idadeDias = duracao.days();
}
```

Não consegui achar o erro!

Comment: qual é o resultado de `hoje.valueOf()` e  de `dia.valueOf()`?

Comment: final: 1436151600000
 nascimento: -394146000000

Comment: É possivel ver um resultado diferente nesse site:http://www.profcardy.com/calculadoras/aplicativos.php?calc=5

Comment: cara, fiz uns teste e, apesar de não ter identificado o porquê, vi que o problema ocorre quando você tenta fazer a diferença com o dia batendo. Um *workaround* seria você adicionar um dia em `hoje`, pegar a duração e, antes de passar os valores de duração, fazer `duracao = duracao.subtract(1,'days')` (é feio, mas foi a alternativa que pensei)

Answer (score 3):

Para calcular a diferença entre um grande intervalo de tempo, calcule separadamente os anos, meses e dias.

Usar milissegundos para calcular uma diferença de meses dificilmente trará o resultado esperado, pois o moment assumirá que todos os meses têm 30 dias.

Exemplo com a data fornecida na pergunta:

```js
var inicio = moment('1957-07-06');
var agora = moment('2015-07-06');

var diferenca = moment.duration({
    years: agora.year() - inicio.year(),
    months: agora.month() - inicio.month(),
    days: agora.date() - inicio.date()
});

document.getElementById("anos").innerHTML = diferenca.years() + ' ano(s)';
document.getElementById("meses").innerHTML = diferenca.months() + ' mes(es)';
document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = diferenca.days() + ' dia(s)';
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p>Se passaram <b id="anos"></b>, <b id="meses"></b> e <b id="dias"></b>.</p>
```

Comment: essa solucao é parcial pois se colocar  as datas seguintes: inicio 05/07/1957 e fim 06/06/2015, o dia ficará -1

Comment: resposta atualizada. O moment.js deveria tratar as datas para isso não acontecer, mas tem um bug aberto que impede que isso aconteça nos casos de dias negativos.

Comment: Opa o bug foi corrigido: https://github.com/ichernev/moment/commit/e3ec1957353406b97562b4585232705651358169, agora é só esperar o merge e o release :-)